# Flash sockets with python server

Tags: python, flash, sockets

I'm try to send and get data using sockets between Adobe flash client and python server.
Flash client:

```
var serverURL = "se.rv.er.ip";
var xmlSocket:XMLSocket = new XMLSocket();
xmlSocket.connect(serverURL, 50007);

xmlSocket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onIncomingData);

function onIncomingData(event:DataEvent):void
{
    trace("[" + event.type + "] " + event.data);
}

xmlSocket.send("Hello World");
```

And python server:

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if (data):
        print 'Received', repr(data)
        # data
        if(str(repr(data)).find('<policy-file-request/>')!=-1):
            print 'received policy'
            conn.send('<?xml version="1.0"?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="50007" /></cross-domain-policy>')
            conn.send('hellow wolrd')
conn.close()
```

But this code not working.
Python server output:

```
Connected by ('cl.ie.nt.ip', 3854)
Received '<policy-file-request/>\x00'
received policy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the socket module if you don't have to. Use [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#module-SocketServer) when you want, well, a socket server.

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
            # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            print "%s wrote:" % self.client_address[0]
            print self.data
            if '<policy-file-request/>' in self.data:
                print 'received policy'
                conn.send('<?xml version="1.0"?><cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="50007" /></cross-domain-policy>')
                conn.send('hellow wolrd')

def main():
    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

It should work this way ..

Comment: i think problem not in python script, with you script i also get 127.0.0.1 wrote:
<policy-file-request/>
received policy and no more